# how to pass a string from a class to two different classes in android?

Tags: android, string, android-intent

I would like to pass a string from a class to two different class I tired to do that by using intent but it does not work, I want to do something like this;

```
String userinfo= listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
String userId = userinfo.substring(0, userinfo.indexOf(" "));

Intent i =new Intent(ShowUserTable.this, UserInfoTableActivity.class);              
    i.putExtra("userId ", userId );
    startActivity(i);
Intent j = new Intent(ShowUserTable.this, ShowUserInfoTable.class);
    j.putExtra("userId ", userId );
    startActivity(j);
```

How can i pass the string "userId" from this class to two different class ?

I am looking forward to hear your answers.

**Log Errors**

```
12-04 14:52:07.968: D/AndroidRuntime(12474): Shutting down VM
12-04 14:52:07.968: W/dalvikvm(12474): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.ShowCoopTable.startActivities
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.ShowCoopTable$1.onItemClick(ShowCoopTable.java:60)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-04 14:52:07.998: E/AndroidRuntime(12474):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.398: D/dalvikvm(12474): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4164 objects / 249872 bytes in 365ms
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi/databases/erp_coop_info.db, table = null, query = Select * from  coop_table WHERE producer_id = 213
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.CoopTableAdapter.returnCoopData(CoopTableAdapter.java:69)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.ShowCoopTable.onCreate(ShowCoopTable.java:41)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi/databases/erp_coop_info.db, table = null, query = Select * from  producer_table WHERE veterinary_id = 123
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.ProducerTableAdapter.returnProducerData(ProducerTableAdapter.java:65)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.ShowProducerTable.onCreate(ShowProducerTable.java:56)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-04 14:52:08.408: E/Cursor(12474):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi/databases/erp_coop_info.db, table = veterinary_table, query = SELECT * FROM veterinary_table WHERE  username=?
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.VeterinaryTableAdapter.getVeterinaryId(VeterinaryTableAdapter.java:92)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:4121)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:4431)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3740)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-04 14:52:08.428: E/Cursor(12474):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi/databases/erp_coop_info.db, table = veterinary_table, query = SELECT * FROM veterinary_table WHERE  username=?
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.VeterinaryTableAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(VeterinaryTableAdapter.java:72)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:4121)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:4431)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3740)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-04 14:52:08.508: E/Cursor(12474):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474): Releasing statement in a finalizer. Please ensure that you explicitly call close() on your cursor: SELECT * FROM veterinary_table WHERE  username=?
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:62)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.VeterinaryTableAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(VeterinaryTableAdapter.java:72)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:4121)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:4431)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3740)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-04 14:52:08.538: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(12474):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi/databases/erp_coop_info.db' 
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:844)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:540)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.VeterinaryTableAdapter.open(VeterinaryTableAdapter.java:39)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at com.erpilic.veterineruygulamasi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-04 14:52:08.598: E/Database(12474):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I edited my answer to cover API Levels lower than 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to launch multiple new activities you have to use [`startActivities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities(android.content.Intent[])) rather than `startActivity`:

```
String userinfo= listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
String userId = userinfo.substring(0, userinfo.indexOf(" "));

Intent i =new Intent(ShowUserTable.this, UserInfoTableActivity.class);              
i.putExtra("userId ", userId );

Intent j = new Intent(ShowUserTable.this, ShowUserInfoTable.class);
j.putExtra("userId ", userId );

startActivities(new Intent[] {i, j});
```

**Note:** `startActivities(Intent[])` was added in API Level 11. If you are using lower versions of android, you have to start your third activity `ShowUserInfoTable` in `onCreate()` method of your second one `UserInfoTableActivity`. As [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities(android.content.Intent[])) says:

> This [startActivities] is generally the same as calling startActivity(Intent) for the
>   first Intent in the array, that activity during its creation calling
>   startActivity(Intent) for the second entry, etc. Note that unlike that
>   approach, generally none of the activities except the last in the
>   array will be created at this point, but rather will be created when
>   the user first visits them (due to pressing back from the activity on
>   top).

Comment: I tried this I don't know why but it gives error :(

Comment: I can not paste log errors here cause it is too long

Comment: ohhh it looks terrible!

Comment: yes when i use one intent it works fine but when i want to use second one it gives error.

Comment: No i did not use cursor in UserInfoTableActivity

Comment: @Ert what is the SDK version of your target?

Comment: It works now but I spent a lot of time to fix the errors after I changed it to Android 5.0 First it showed up as landscape screen and then a lot of "running android lint" errors now it is fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In activity2 u should use
Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
String inputString=extras.getString("userId);

Comment: I did not get exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making that string `public`and having your two classes inherit from your main activity? You're saying you want to pass it to two classes, but didn't mention they're activities, so maybe you don't need to start them.